# How to get column definition from query result

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I need a way to get column definition from query result. Right now I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Here is the example scenario, I have two tables which are Event and Attendant whose definitions are below :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Event] (
    [Id]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Description]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [StartDate]       DATETIME      NULL,
    [EndDate] DATETIME      NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attendant] (
    [Id]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [EventId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Name]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Company]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And then I have query such as :

```
SELECT Event.Name as EventName, Attendant.Name as GuestName
FROM Event
   INNER JOIN Attendant ON Event.Id = Attendant.EventId
```

How Can I get the column definition for above example query result? My objective is to generate poco class to represent each record of any query result using c#.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sp_columns sproc to retrieve information about the column definition of a specified table ... like this:

```
exec sp_columns Attendant
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_columns`, it returns column information for the specified objects(tables).

Refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '<tablename>'
```